# Force property type to doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen

For example:

```
class Test
{
    /// This var contain Apple class
    void* something;
};
```

I know that "something" will be pointed to the object of Apple type. How can i force tell that to doxygen (for DOT graphs relations).

Comment: _"I know that "something" will be pointed to the object of Apple type."_  If you know that, then why is `something` not an `Apple*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be a bit heavy handed, but one way would be to conditionally declare it as an `Apple*` when processing it with doxygen:

```
class Test
{
    /// This var contain Apple class
#ifdef DOXYGEN_INVOKED
    Apple* something;
#else
    void* something;
#endif
};
```

You can configure Doxygen to define the `DOXYGEN_INVOKED` macro by using the [PREDEFINED](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_predefined) tag.

Answer (score 2):

Programming design aside, you can do this:

```
class Test
{
    #ifdef DOXYGEN_RUNNING
        Apple* something;
    #else
        void* something;
    #endif
};
```

And then have Doxygen predefine `DOXYGEN_RUNNING`. ([Manual for preprocessing](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/preprocessing.html).)

---

(But seriously: if it's gonna be an `Apple*` just write it that way.)

Answer (score 1):

You tell this to Doxygen by declaring your pointer correctly as `Apple* something`.